# can we join two rdd with two keys using join function in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

Like for instance :

```python
rdd1 = [('magnus', 'nordea', 13000), ('Erik', 'nordea', 13000), ('Ola', 'nordea', 19000), ('rohit', 'nordea', 23030)]
rdd2 = [('magnus', 'jpmc', 14000), ('Erik', 'jpmc', 2100), ('Ola', 'jpmc', 18400), ('rohit', 'jpmc', 25000)]


rdd1.join(rdd2).collect() gives me :
[('Ola', ('nordea', 'jpmc')), ('Erik', ('nordea', 'jpmc')), ('rohit', ('nordea', 'jpmc')), ('magnus', ('nordea', 'jpmc'))]
```

The above rdd loses its amount value :(

Required output :

```python
[(('Ola','nordea'),13000),
 (('Ola','jpmc'),14000),
 (('Erik','nordea'),13000),
 (('Erik','jpmc'),2100),
 (('rohit','nordea'),23030), 
 (('rohit','jpmc'),25000), 
 (('magnus','nordea'),13000),
 (('magnus', 'jpmc'),14000)]
```

Any suggestions on it or what function I should refer to?

Comment: Welcome to SO; if you have found some answer useful, please accept it (or provide feedback) - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
spark.version
#  u'2.2.0'

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('magnus', 'nordea', 13000), ('Erik', 'nordea', 13000), ('Ola', 'nordea', 19000), ('rohit', 'nordea', 23030)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([('magnus', 'jpmc', 14000), ('Erik', 'jpmc', 2100), ('Ola', 'jpmc', 18400), ('rohit', 'jpmc', 25000)])

rdd1.union(rdd2).map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), x[2])).collect()
```

Result:

```python
[(('magnus', 'nordea'), 13000), 
 (('Erik', 'nordea'), 13000),
 (('Ola', 'nordea'), 19000),
 (('rohit', 'nordea'), 23030), 
 (('magnus', 'jpmc'), 14000),
 (('Erik', 'jpmc'), 2100),
 (('Ola', 'jpmc'), 18400),
 (('rohit', 'jpmc'), 25000)]
```

Comment: I took it liitle further and got my expected results :

nordeardd=rdd1_temp.join(rdd2_temp).map(lambda x:((x[0],x[1][0][0]),x[1][0][1]))
jpmcrdd = rdd1_temp.join(rdd2_temp).map(lambda x:((x[0],x[1][1][0]),x[1][1][1]))

result = nordeardd.union(jpmcrdd)
result.collect()
[(('Ola', 'nordea'), 19000), (('Erik', 'nordea'), 13000), (('rohit', 'nordea'), 23030), (('magnus', 'nordea'), 13000), (('Ola', 'jpmc'), 18400), (('Erik', 'jpmc'), 2100), (('rohit', 'jpmc'), 25000), (('magnus', 'jpmc'), 14000)]
but this is lot of code and may have performance issue. any better trick if we can implement

Comment: @S.Jain forget it, along with my temporary RDDs.See updated answer (and kindly accept it)

Answer (score 0):

```
     rdd1.union(rdd2).collect()
```

Output:

```
    [('magnus', 'nordea', 13000),
     ('Erik', 'nordea', 13000),
     ('Ola', 'nordea', 19000),
     ('rohit', 'nordea', 23030),
     ('magnus', 'jpmc', 14000),
     ('Erik', 'jpmc', 2100),
     ('Ola', 'jpmc', 18400),
     ('rohit', 'jpmc', 25000)]
```